# File between backend a front end (full example)

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, docker

I'm passing a file url to the front end. The problem is that url is only available to the server (`settings.dockerIP()`) because the user doesn't have connection to the docker.

So I need a way to transform my url into a file and then send it to the user all in the backend..

My current code is like this (it works but the user needs a tunnel to docker host)

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping("/report")
public ModelAndView report(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String environmentName = request.getParameter("name");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("report");    
    model.addObject("file", Report.getFileFromContainer(environmentName));

    return model;
}
```

Class

```
 public static String getFileFromContainer(String environmentName) {
    Container container = getContainerID(environmentName);
    String url = "";
    if(container != null) {
        Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
        url = "http://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort() + "/containers/" + container.getId() + "/archive?path=/path/file";
    }
    return url;
}
```

Front end

```
 <a href="${file}"></a>
```

Comment: create a an endpoint in which you return the file as outputStream attahcment when clicking on the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in wich your return a file as a stream , the you assign the url of this last to your link button ,

```
@RequestMapping(value="getFile", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) {
     String environmentName = request.getParameter("name");
    //here the code to get your file as stream 
    //whether getting the file by Ressource or buffred ,
    //here for example I named a getfileStream() method wihch return your file  InputStream
    InputStream myStream  = getFileStream(environmentName);


    // Set the content type and attachment header add filename and it's extention.
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile.myExtention");
    response.setContentType("txt/plain");

    // copy your file stream to Response 
    IOUtils.copy(myStream, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

in order to get the name `parameter` you just pass it to the `modelview` in the `/report` controller , an then assign it to your link .

As below :

```
@RequestMapping("/report")
public ModelAndView report(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String environmentName = request.getParameter("name");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("report");    
    model.addObject("name", environmentName);

    return model;
}
```

then your link would be like :

```
<a href="<c:url value="/getFile" />?name=${name}">Get file</a>
```

the getFileStream could be like :

```
public InputStream getFileStream(String environmentName) {
    Container container = getContainerID(environmentName);
    String url = "";
    if(container != null) {
        Settings settings = Settings.getSettings();
        url = "http://" + settings.getDockerIP() + ":" + settings.getDockerPort() + "/containers/" + container.getId() + "/archive?path=/path/file";
    }
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();

    return is; 
}
```

You have to add the following appace common io to your project in order to use the [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: and how do I download it first from the url?

Comment: from where the envirenemnt name is sent ? from where did get or grab this information

Comment: url. and I get this  String environmentName = request.getParameter("name");